# munin-node installation on 10.7 OSX host

Tags: mac-osx, munin

We've got a pretty good setup in house for using nagios + munin-node to monitor the various boxes.

having some trouble getting munin-node going on our first OSX server (10.7 mac mini server model)

the only guide i was able to find is http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/DarwinInstallation - but it leaves much to be desired.

anyone have any experience, or guides for getting munin-node going on an OSX box?